# Mysql & Joins Getting the desired results

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have a players table with the following fields that matter.

```
id| team_id| first_name| last_name
```

I also have a pivot called event_player table containing the following fields.

```
event_id| player_id| availability| availability_notes
```

Now I need to fetch all the users that play for team_id = 1 but then also show if they are available for that event from the event_player table in the same sql.

if i run

```
select * from `players` where team_id=1 ;
```

I will get back all 17 players that currently play for team_id 1

but I now need to see if they are available or not so i tried

```
select * from `players`  
     JOIN event_player
ON event_player.player_id=players.id where team_id=1 and event_id=1 ;
```

but this only show the players that exist in the event_player and at the minute only 10 players have replied for this event.

How can I also show the players that have not yet replied without showing all the other events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
 FROM `players`  
    LEFT JOIN `event_player` ON event_player.`event_id`=1
ON event_player.player_id=players.id where team_id=1 ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON event_player.player_id=players.id where team_id=1' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

You should use `left join`.
It will give you also reaults that appear in the first table only

Comment: If i do a left join i get the same returned i guess the where's are not helping as it still only returns ones that have the event_id of 1 in the events_player table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column availability to be of varchar, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM player p 
LEFT JOIN event_player e ON p.`id`=e.`player_id` 
WHERE p.`team_id`=1 AND p.`id` IN(
SELECT ee.`player_id`  
FROM event_player ee 
WHERE ee.`availability`='Yes');
```

Comment: availability is a tinyint.

Comment: This is getting there but it is also returning the other events availability's too. So for event 1,2,3,4,5 etc. and i only need event=1

Comment: instead try giving a tinyint value for availability

Answer (score 0):

Sorted...

```
SELECT *
 FROM `players`  
    LEFT JOIN `event_player` 
    ON event_player.`event_id`=1
    AND event_player.player_id=players.id where team_id=1 ;
```

Thanks Subin C Poonamgode and all you others!